# Linq updating different table after join process

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, join

I have combined 3 of my tables by using linq join. After that i want to update this table by using data that i get from webform. How can i do this ? My implementation is below

```
public void updateShoes(Shoe shoe) 
{
    var query = from b in db.BrandTbls.AsQueryable()
                join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID
                join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID
                where shoe.ShoeID == s.ShoeID 
                orderby m.ModelName
                select new 
                { 
                    s.ShoeID,
                    s.Size,
                    s.PrimaryColor,
                    s.SecondaryColor,
                    s.Quantity,
                    m.ModelName,
                    m.Price,
                    b.BrandName
                };
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: And where do you want to persist your data with LINQ? If it's database then only LINQ is insufficient, you IAC using linqprovider that knows how to convert linq methods to sql. Do you have SaveChanges() method on you db object?

Comment: Yes i have this method.

Comment: Most likely you are using EntityFramework, you can see it in your project references. Doing these joins before update seems unnecessary to me because I think that you should change data only in one table. What properties of shoe do you want to update?

Comment: I want to update all properties that i select in the join query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though your approach is a little bit unclear right now (for e.g. we don't know which entities you are trying to update), however you can modify your code like this,

```
public void updateShoes(Shoe shoe) 
{
    var query = from b in db.BrandTbls.AsQueryable()
            join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID
            join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID
            where shoe.ShoeID == s.ShoeID 
            orderby m.ModelName
            select new 
            { 
                Shoe = shoe, Brand = b, Model = m
            };

    foreach(var o in query)
    {
        o.Shoe.ColorName = "Black";
        o.Brand.BrandName = "New Branding";
        o.Model.ModelName = "Something else";
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Rather picking selected properties from each Entity, you can pick whole entity. Then you can update each entity in a loop as I have doing above.

Answer (score 2):

I like the all-in-one linq update. Especially if I need to join on an existing object list.

```
var UpdQuery = (from b in db.BrandTbls
            join m in db.ShoeModelTbls on b.BrandID equals m.BrandID
            join s in db.ShoeTbls on m.ModelID equals s.ModelID
            where shoe.ShoeID == s.ShoeID 
            orderby m.ModelName
            select new { b, m, s }
            // now for the update portion of the query
            ).Select(result =>
            { 
                result.s.ShoeID = shoe.ID;
                result.s.Size = shoe.Size;
                result.s.PrimaryColor = shoe.PrimaryColor;
                result.s.SecondaryColor = shoe.SecondaryColor;
                result.s.Quantity = shoe.Quantity;
                result.m.ModelName = shoe.ModelName;
                result.m.Price = shoe.Price;
                result.b.BrandName = shoe.BrandName;
                return result; // this is important
            }).ToList();  // tolist actually runs the query to update the objects
db.SaveChanges(); // write changes back to DB
```

Comment: Hi @sean, does your query actually run fully on the db server (i.e. translate into an UPDATE sql-statement or does it make a round to the DB server, make the modifications  on the web server and then writes it back to the DB server?

Comment: Hey @Tim , the first statement that ends with ToList() gets the data from the DB and then updates the tables as they exist in memory within the db context. The save changes statement figures out which rows are "dirty" and makes a call to update the database tables.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then I will have to look further for a solution that does run onlz on the db, i.e. translates to a single UPDATE query.

Answer (score 1):

To update an entity you will need to retrieve the entity from the context, modify the values, then call SaveChanges() to do the update.

```
foreach( var n in query)
{
  var shoe = db.Shoes.Find(n.ShoeID);
  shoe.Size = webFormData.Size;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality due to its brevity. Consider adding some text to explain the code & how it answers the question.